# Why I can not migrate db using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I got to create database using db:create and generate migrate file.

migrations:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      await queryInterface.createTable('users', {id: Sequelize.INTEGER});  
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
     await queryInterface.dropTable('users');     
  }
};
```

file: .sequelizerc

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    'config': path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "config", "database"),
    'migrations-path': path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "databases", "migrations")
}
```

Why I can not create the tables, the path is correct, if "migrations-path" were wrong it can not be able  to generate migrations files.

```
npx sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 15.3.0, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.5.0]


ERROR: Cannot find "/home/thiago/Documents/Coding/Node/movies/src/config/database". Have you run "sequelize init"?
```

Comment: Do you have the requested folder/file in the expected path?

Comment: To generate initial migrations `migrations-path` is used, while to apply migrations `config` is used to connect to db. Check `config` path